# Trying to remove index.php from urls

Tags: .htaccess, routes, symfony4, production-environment

**I'm working on an apache secured web server hosted on an ubuntu-server.16.04

I'm sending on prod my first project on symfony and I did quite well since now. I'm trying to rewrite url so when I want to go on my project dashboard, the url would be "../dashboard/" instead of (actually like this) "../index.php/dashboard/"

But when I try to go on this url, the server redirect me out of the symfony app and throw me a basic apache 404 error, not a symfony handled error.

I think this can be edited in the .htaccess file but I can't find out how to make him perform all url as symfony routes, that's my question.

Tried multiple code found on google

htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}::$1 ^(/.+)/(.*)::\2$
    RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=BASE:%1]
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule ^ - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
    RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
    RewriteRule ^index\.php(?:/(.*)|$) %{ENV:BASE}/$1 [R=301,L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
    RewriteRule ^ - [L]
    RewriteRule ^ %{ENV:BASE}/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_alias.c>
        RedirectMatch 302 ^/$ /index.php/
    </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

Comment: In which directory are you putting this `.htaccess` file? Can you show the relevant lines from your apache config file?

Comment: .htaccess is located in public dir.

***.ssl :

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName www.***.fr
   Redirect / https://www.***.fr/
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    ServerAdmin gmail.com
    ServerName ***.fr
    ServerAlias www.***.fr
    DocumentRoot /var/www/portfolio/public
    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
    SSLEngine on
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/***.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/***.key
    SSLCertificateChainFile /etc/ssl/***.ca-bundle
</VirtualHost>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to enable apache rewrite.
Please follow these steps :
In a terminal use the following commands:

```
$sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

Change AllowOverride in apache conf file:

```
$sudo nano /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

Change the AllowOverride from None to All in this block

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

At last, restart apache2

```
$sudo service apache2 restart
```